# Jquery form validation how to require minimum input

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I am trying to figure out how to get my jquery validation working so that if a value is less than the desired amount it will display the error code. I can't figure out how to make this work correctly. It requires at least one character to be input but I want it to be at least 4.

Any help appreciated

My validation code looks like

```
   if($('#firstname').val() < 3){
                $('#firstname').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("First Name is Required");
                err++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($('#firstname').val().length < 4){
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the actual value of the string instead of the length like I assume you want to.  just add a .length to your condition.  Like so:

`if($('#firstname').val().length < 4)`

Answer (score 0):

The `.length` may simply fix your problem.
But I suggest using regex to check the input, otherwise user can just input 4 space which will also past the `.length` check.

```
str = "    " # 4 space
str.length >= 4 # => true
str.match(/^\w{4}.*$/) # => null
another_str = "someinput"
another_str.match(/^\w{4}.*$/) # => ["someinput"]
```